# How to format arrays into one with new index in php

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to format my code as shown below. But failed to do so.

My criteria and my code is mentioned below.

Here is my array structure:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [tagged_field] => description
                    [created_date] => 2015-02-06 14:47:44
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [tagged_field] => description_html
                    [created_date] => 2015-02-06 14:47:44
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [tagged_field] => description_html
                    [created_date] => 2015-02-06 14:47:44
                )

        )

)
```

Desired array structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tagged_field] => description
            [created_date] => 2015-02-06 14:47:44
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tagged_field] => description_html
            [created_date] => 2015-02-06 14:47:44
        )
[2] => Array
        (
            [tagged_field] => description_html
            [created_date] => 2015-02-06 14:47:44
        )
)
```

My code :

```
foreach($tagArr as $key => $value){
            $a_tag[$inc] = $value[0];
            $inc++;
        }
```

But was not able to format array like that.....

How can i sort my array as shown in desired format if my input array is mentioned as above.

Answer (score 1):

Try with -

```
foreach($tagArr as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $val) {
            $a_tag[] = $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: but you don't have to use the `$inc++;` anymore

Comment: @user3797205 If the keys were same then the second loop can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($tagArr as $key => $value){
    $a_tag[] = array_values($value[0]);     
}
```

Use this

Comment: can't use array_values it destroys index like "tagged_field"

Answer (score 0):

```
$a_tag = [];
foreach ($tagArr as $value) {
     $a_tag += $value;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using the following code:

```
foreach($tagArr as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $val) {
          $a_tag[] = $val;
    }
}
```